# How do I add my own Custom Regular Expressions to the RegularExpressionValidator in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a bunch of regular expressions which I commonly use on WebForms `RegularExpressionValidators` as the `ValidationExpression`.

At the moment I need to copy paste the RegEx from similar controls or from a text file.
Is there any way to extend the current list of Standard Expressions in the designer Drop Down (and can I delete patterns that I don't use like French phone number, French post code etc)?

**Edit** Hopefully this picture clarifies the issue

[image: Regex]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do so is by adding a normal RegularExpressionValidator and instead of the properties they give you in the ValidationExpression add your own their.